# Saving a doctrine2 entity to cache to speed up the page load

Tags: zend-framework, caching, doctrine-orm, memcached

Let's say I have an entity called `Product` and this entity is loaded every time user hits the product information page. Usually I'd save the object in Zend_Cache (memcache) for an hour to avoid hitting the db for each request but as far as I understand that's not possible with Doctrine2 entities because of the Proxy objects.

So my question is, how can I avoid loading the same entity from the database for each request?

**[EDIT]**

I tried using Doctrine Cache like this

> ```
>     $categoryService = App_Service_Container::getService('\App\Service\Category');
>     $cache = $categoryService->getEm()->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl();
>     $apple = $cache->fetch('apple');
> ```

But I get the following error

> Warning: require(App/Entity/Proxy/**_*CG*_**/App/Entity/Category.php)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /opt/vhosts/app/price/library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on
>   line 163

This is same for Zend Cache as well as you can't serialize the entity because of the Proxy class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got several options:

1. Use Doctrine's [built-in result caching](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html#integrating-with-the-orm)
2. Try just sticking entity in memcache via Zend_Cache.  When you pull it out, you may need to merge() the Product back into the EM so proxies can be dereferenced.  If you fetch-join any associations you need to display the product info, and you're only doing reads, this shoudl work fine.
3. Don't cache the entity at all.  Cache whatever output you generate instead.

**EDIT**:  If you don't care about the hydration overhead, you're using mysql, and your Products and associated tables don't change very often, you might prefer to just rely on the mySQL query cache.  It's a fairly blunt object, but useful enough to mention.

Comment: 1. For this to work, I need to overwrite repository methods such as `find`, `findBy*`, right?
2. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try implementing `__sleep` or `__wakeup` methods for your entity class, as Doctrine 2 has special requirements and limitations concerning serialization/deserialization of entities (which is what happens when storing them in Zend_Cache).

- There is this [guidance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html).
- General information about [limitations including serialization](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#entities).

Answer (score 0):

I find this extremely strange since i just messed around with this myself and didn't have any issues with the proxy object being stored in the database. So im guessing your configuration is not setup 100% ?

If you find the issue with your configuration then be very aware of what timdev said you *MUST* merge the object back into the EntityManager else you will have weird bugs down the line.

A fourth solution available for you is also to retrieve the data as an array instead of an object, but then of course you lose all the functionality connected to your module which might not be exactly want you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me more like a configuration error. Either Proxies have not been generated or there is something wrong with the proxy directory and namespace.

Depending on your configuration, proxies can be either generated automatically or manually. Does your proxies have been indeed generated under `App/Entity/Proxy` ? Is this indeed the right directory?

FYI proxies can be manually generated by executing `doctrine orm:generate-proxies <dest-dir>`

Answer (score 0):

Seconding what timdev says: Doctrine has built-in caching, you want to use it.

I also wonder from your question if you are experiencing any performance issues or if you are a victim of overly eager optimisation.